# How I run On Group And Calc

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class UserMessages
    {
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("fk")]
        public long fk{ get; set; }
        public virtual fk fk{ get; set; }

        public long ChatMateId { get; set; }

        public string text { get; set; }

        public DateTime? dateTime { get; set; }

        public bool read { get; set; }

    }
```

I need help in this line

```
numberOfNewMessage = c.s.userMessages.GroupBy(x=>x.ChatMateId).
```

I got groups by ChatMateId

I want to return to the numberOfNewMessage property count of new messages

I need to run every group if there one message inside that have `bool read= false`  then i add to `numberOfNewMessage` 1

how i do it?

**example:**

If I have 3 group with 10 messages each and all the messages is `bool read` is false, i need to set the `numberOfNewMessage` with value 3.

Comment: have you done a google search on how to do `GroupBy` in a lambda statement. here is some previous asked questions with answers that you can try in regards to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101824/groupby-in-lamda-expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want the number of groups that have at least one unread message:

```
int numberOfNewMessage = msgs.GroupBy(m => m.ChatMateId)
                             .Count(m => m.Any(x => !x.read));
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly. You want the count of messages under each key. That would be:

```
var numberOfNewMessage = c.s.userMessages
    .GroupBy(x=>x.ChatMateId)
    .Select(x=> new{Key = x.Key, Unread = x.Count(m => !m.Read)});
```

Answer (score 0):

I try simply count unread messages.

```
numberOfNewMessage = c.s.userMessages.GroupBy(x=>x.ChatMateId)
                                     .Count(msg=> !msg.Read);
```