# Lambda function using group by

Tags: c#, linq

```
var result = booklist.GroupJoin(authorlist, authorlist2,
    x => x.ISBN,
    y => y.AuthorId,
    z => z.AuthorID,
    (x, y, z) => new
    {
        x.Book_Name,
        y.AuthorName,
        z.AuthorName
    }).GroupBy(od => new
{
    od.Book_Name,
    od.AuthorName
}).OrderBy(d => d.Key.Book_Name).Select(grp => new

{
    AuthorName = grp.Key.AuthorName,
    Book_Name = grp.Key.Book_Name,
});

foreach (var item in result)

{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format(" BookName:-   {0}\n AuthorName:- {1}\n", item.Book_Name, item.AuthorName));
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ci6C4.png)

Here I used lambda function to print one book and two author name but showing error on GroupJoin. plz check and tell me where I did mistake

Comment: please indicate as much details as possible, like what kind of error is it?

Comment: "but showing error on GroupJoin" - so what's the error? Can you reduce the complexity of the code in the question by removing the `GroupBy` and `OrderBy` parts? I would definitely try to reduce this to a [mcve] so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: also adding class definitions would be informative

Comment: Someone Already answered your question here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3101824/groupby-in-lambda-expressions

Comment: @JonSkeet I need GroupBy... I want to print result using GroupBy in lambda expression

Comment: I saw but I want to join 3 list using groupby and he shows only two without groupby @ShahMeer

Comment: "I need GroupBy" - sure, eventually. But I'd expect your *immediate* goal is to fix the `GroupJoin` call. Do you need to include the `GroupBy` call in order to demonstrate the `GroupJoin` problem? It's really important to fix one problem at a time, and to be able to focus on just that problem.

Comment: You may need to provide the exact error you were getting on the GroupJoin

Comment: now check  I added SS of error  @Mahi

Answer (score 1):

The error description says that GroupJoin method has no overload with six parameters. GroupJoin can contact only two lists by two navigation properties, one from each list.

After concatenation of list grouping will look like:

```
var result = booklist.GroupJoin(concatenatedAuthorlist,
        left => left .AuthorId,  // navigation from booklist
        right => right .AuthorID,  // navigation from concatenatedAuthorlist
        (left, right) => new
        {
            left.Book_Name,
            left.AuthorName,
            right.AuthorName
        }).
        //omitted for brevity
```